# Можно ли добавить параметр для текущей сессии hibernate и получить его в связанном компоненте, который добавлен как зависимость?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть веб-сервис на Spring, в котором при помощи hibernate event listener перехватываются различные события (insert/update/delete). Этот перехватчик вынесен в отдельный проект и подключается к веб-сервису в зависимостях. Мне необходимо в основном проекте для текущей сессии в одной транзакции установить некий параметр, который я бы смог получить в обработчике событий.

Пробовал установить через свойства EntityManager:

```
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final TestService service;

@PostMapping
public Long save(@RequestBody TestEntity entity) {
    entityManager.setProperty("TEST_PARAM", true);
    return service.save(entity).getId();
}
```

Но при перехвате события это свойство отсутствует:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TestEventListener implements PostInsertEventListener {
private final EntityManager entityManager;

...

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        if (Objects.equals(true, entityManager.getProperties().get("TEST_PARAM"))) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Почему так не выходит, если это всё происходит в одной транзакции?
Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ это сделать?

Comment: А вот эти объекты private final EntityManager entityManager у Вас где создаются? Вы код с их созданием не показали или я чего-то совсем не понимаю? Транзакции сами определяют свои EntityManager. Наверное, Ваши  final EntityManager entityManager - это разные объекты и не привязанные к транзакции, которая предположительно у Вас одна. Если Вам все еще интересен этот вопрос воспользуйтесь [Монитором Транзакций](http://konopkomikl.ru/2020/10/23/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-transactional-%d0%b2-springdata/)

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою задачу другим способом:
Создал бин, который создаётся на каждый новый запрос и по завершению уничтожается:

```
public class SessionAttributes extends HashMap<String, Object> {
}
```

---

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,
        proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public SessionAttributes requestAttributes() {
    return new SessionAttributes();
}
```

И далее просто выполняю инъекцию там, где мне это необходимо